# ¿como imprimir un array de 20 elementos en 5 filas de cuatro columnas con php?

Tags: php

Si tengo un arreglo de 20 elementos, quisiera saber si hay una forma de recorrerlo de tal forma que muestre en pantalla 5 filas de cuatro columnas? Gracias...

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Sí, hay una forma. ¿Puedes decirnos qué has intentado hacer y qué problema te has encontrado? Por favor, revisa [help], [ask] y [faq].

Comment: pues la verdad es una consulta de BD, entonces las filas de esa columna las meto en un arreglo, y luego ese arreglo lo recorro con un foreach, he probado recorrerlo con un for(), verificar los multiplos de 4 pero no me resulta

Comment: Por favor trata de colocar el código con los intentos realizados hasta ahora de esa forma es más facil que podamos ayudarte. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de mil maneras, esta una:

```
<?php
    $elementos = array(
        array("nombre" => "Pepe", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Carmen", "edad" => "21"),
        array("nombre" => "Sofía", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Jose", "edad" => "21"),
        array("nombre" => "Raul", "edad" => "22"),
        array("nombre" => "Elena", "edad" => "22"),
        array("nombre" => "Carlos", "edad" => "25"),
        array("nombre" => "Ramón", "edad" => "19"),
        array("nombre" => "Silvia", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Raquel", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Sergio", "edad" => "23"),
        array("nombre" => "Sandra", "edad" => "22"),
        array("nombre" => "Pedro", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Mirella", "edad" => "21"),
        array("nombre" => "Clara", "edad" => "20"),
        array("nombre" => "Toni", "edad" => "23"),
        array("nombre" => "Ferrán", "edad" => "22"),
        array("nombre" => "Montse", "edad" => "22"),
        array("nombre" => "Pilar", "edad" => "21"),
        array("nombre" => "Francisca", "edad" => "19")
    );
    $cols = 4;
    $i = 0;
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($elementos as $el) {
        if($cols == $i) $i = 0; // Nueva fila, comenzar de nuevo
            if($i == 0) { // Es nueva fila, pintar tr
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<td>" . $el["nombre"] . " (" . $el["edad"] . ")</td>"; // El valor
            if($cols == $i) { // Cerrar nueva fila
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
```